# Should I be worried about "Missing semicolon" in JSLint?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the following:

```
$.ajaxSetup({beforeSend:function(a){a.setRequestHeader("Accept","text/javascript")},cache:false});
```

JSLint is telling me: "Problem at line 1 character 83: Missing semicolon"

Do you agree? I added it, but when I use YUI Compressor it removes it?

Thanks

Comment: I don't use semi-colons, except where required per ASI. However, I also don't write code like that because it's hard to read/parse (for a human) -- with good formatting rules, writing semi-colon free code neither causes additional problems nor confusion. With bad formatting rules, explicit semi-colons are the least of your worries.

Answer (score 5):

> **JSLint will hurt your feelings.**

- Douglas Crockford

And in 90% of the cases it does nothing more, it may complain about the missing semicolon, but the code still works fine, since it's technically not required at that position, so YUI compressor removes it to save the byte.

Answer (score 4):

JSLint tries to detect potential bugs, just as warning signs. As such it should be used on **working code**, and **not compressed code**.

Answer (score 3):

The compressor removes it to save bytes being sent (smaller filesize / quicker download).

Optional semicolons can be the cause of problems, e.g.

```
function a() {

   return // <-- semi colon is inserted here, terminating the line.
     {
         abc: '???'
     }
}

alert(a()); // undefined
```

I always explicitly add my semi colons, and do [BSD KNF style indenting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#BSD_KNF_style).

Do not worry what the compressor does - if your code runs fine, it is all good.

#### Update

[Pst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166390/pst) points out in the comments (cheers) that ASI isn't the problem above - the grammar of `return` expects the value to be immediately after it. Still, I think ASI could still be a problem there - if each `\n` gets a `;` preceding it automatically.

I whipped up another example of ASI being a PITA.

```
var a = function(b) {
    
    b.call();  
    
};

(function() {
    c = 'hello',
    a
        
    (function() {
        alert('hello')  
    })
    
})();
```

[See it on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/NEvXB/).

The code looks pretty stupid (why is the `a` variable floating there)?

A novice coder may not know of `var` scoping variables, and may build a list of two variables like that. They may then wrap a function in parenthesis (this person is still learning:)).

In the example above, the function will be sent to `a()` and executed.

Comment: That actually is not a problem of ASI, which it is so often attributed to. Even without ASI (or with an explicit `;` at the end of that) that would still occur. It is a restriction in the grammar wrt `return` and friends. There are better examples of where ASI can bite (`x\n(...)`, for instance)

Comment: @pst I think I know what you mean. I'll try think of a new example :)

Answer (score 0):

A semicolon is not required for correct javascript, but jslint helps you find potential bugs and not necessarily broken javascript. You can safely ignore that error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is required version for JSLint

```
$.ajaxSetup({beforeSend:function(a){a.setRequestHeader("Accept","text/javascript");},cache:false});
```

Note: I've added ; to setRequestHeader function call.